# Can you explain me this specific line of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, web-deployment

```
var newstr= str.replace(/[\W_]/g, '');    //replace all non-alfanumeric blank
```

This was the code i tried while removing the non-alfanumeric characters from a string in Javascript.

Please explain what is the difference between `</[\W_]/g>` and `</\w+/g>` and `</\w/g>`.

Comment: Why haven't you tried to find the explanation yourself?

Comment: Check [regex online tutorial](https://regexone.com/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: i tried....But didn't find this specific answer to my question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If we have **/[\W_]/g** any of this special symbols in **str** object replace the empty("") value.

Answer (score 1):

`\w` : 1 word character. It's equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

`\w+` : 1 or more word characters.

`\W` : 1 non-word character. It's equivalent to `[^\w]` or `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`
       So `\W` is anything that's not a letter, not a digit and not an underscore.

`[\W_]` : A character class with non-word characters and underscore.
It's equivalent to `[^A-Za-z0-9]`

Note that with a **g**lobal replace to nothing, the code `str.replace(/\W/g,'')` will give the same result as `str.replace(/\W+/g,'')`. The former will just replace them 1 character at a time, while the latter will replace groups of 1 or more characters at the time.

More info about the regex syntax can be found in [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Or you could just copy&paste your regex in an online regex tester.
For example [regexr](http://regexr.com/) or [regex101](https://regex101.com/)
Then check out the explain, or hover your mouse pointer over the pattern to get hints about each part of the pattern.